# Problem with communication via Modbus RTU with MultiCONT PRD-28-2 - Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

I have a problem with communication via Modbus RTU. First of all sorry for my English ;):

1. I'm using RS485 Pi SN65HVD72 to connect with MultiCONT PRD-28-2. I made everything like is in this instruction: https://www.abelectronics.co.uk/kb/article/1035/raspberry-pi-3-serial-port-usage

config.txt changes:

- toverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt
- enable_uart=1

After this steps the config of my /dev looks like this:

- lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           7 gru 30 15:03 serial0 -> ttyAMA0
- lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           5 gru 30 15:03 serial1 -> ttyS0

2. In MultiCONT PRD-28-2 I change RS485 options to:

- Protocol: Modbus
- Parity: ODD
- Stop bit: 1 bit

3. Python code:

```py
    from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
    import logging

    FORMAT = ('%(asctime)-15s %(threadName)-15s'
    ' %(levelname)-8s %(module)-15s:%(lineno)-8s %(message)s')
    logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
    log = logging.getLogger()
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    #multicont = ModbusClient(method='rtu',port='/dev/serial0',stopbits=1,bytsize=8,parity='N',baudrate=9600,timeout=1,strict=False)
    multicont = ModbusClient(method='rtu',port='/dev/serial0',stopbits=1,bytsize=8,parity='O',baudrate=9600,timeout=1,strict=False)
    connection = multicont.connect()
    print(connection)
    value = multicont.read_coils(1,15,unit=1)
    log.debug(value)
```

4. Error message:

> Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message]
> Incomplete message received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received)

5. Logs:

> 2020-12-30 16:24:51,992 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :118
> Current transaction state - IDLE
>  2020-12-30 16:24:51,992
> MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :123      Running transaction
> 1
>  2020-12-30 16:24:51,992 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction
> :230      SEND: 0x1 0x1 0x0 0x1 0x0 0xf 0x2d 0xce
>  2020-12-30
> 16:24:51,993 MainThread      DEBUG    sync           :75       New
> Transaction state 'SENDING'
>  2020-12-30 16:24:51,993 MainThread
> DEBUG    transaction    :239      Changing transaction state from
> 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
>  2020-12-30 16:24:52,995
> MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :253      Transaction failed.
> (Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected
> at least 2 bytes (0 received)) 
>  2020-12-30 16:24:52,995
> MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :241      Frame - [b''] not
> ready
>  2020-12-30 16:24:52,996 MainThread      DEBUG
> transaction    :409      Getting transaction 1
>  2020-12-30
> 16:24:52,996 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :204
> Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to
> 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
>  2020-12-30 16:24:52,996 MainThread
> DEBUG    communication  :20       Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus
> Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at
> least 2 bytes (0 received)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyModbus is not receiving a response.

If you have access to an oscilloscope, this is the moment to use it. There are soooo many things that can go wrong with Modbus-RTU.

Make sure you know what you are doing with the electrical wiring, familiarize yourself with RS485 biasing and termination.

Possible causes:

- request sent to wrong serial device/interface
- device uses different baudrate or serial settings
- device can hear you allright but has a different slave ID configured, so it doesn't respond
- wrong wiring, grounding issues
- RS485 electrical problems, most notably the master must be biasing the bus, usually via a resistor that you have to solder/enable
- Bus termination resistors are required for correct voltage levels (sometimes they are already built-in, more often you need to enable them, with some luck may work without)
- Master still driving the RS485 bus while the slave is responding. (If you do not have a dedicated RS485 driver, the bus may end up being asserted/deasserted by unreliable software timers. Some devices allow you to configure a response delay as a workaround.)
- Master not driving the bus at all. (Working in RS232 mode instead of RS485 mode.)
- Also, Linux might have ttyAMA0 configured as a serial console for boot/kernel messages. (This is unlikely to cause your current problem, just something else to watch out for.)

Final piece of advice: if you have the option to use Modbus-TCP instead of Modbus-RTU, *do that instead*. This replaces all the RS485 electrical headaches which IP-configuration headaches, for which you can use over-the-counter medication.

Comment: The problem was with hardware. I checked information about termination resistors in MultiCONT documentation. I turn off resistor in MultiCONT and now everything is correct. Thank you very much for your help.